# if specific select option is chosen get the value of input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a little knowledge of php, but this is what I'm trying to do. I have a `form` with `select option`. If an option is selected with the value "example_5" I want it to get the value of an `<input>`. Is this done with php or jquery to use the value of input?

For example: someone selects example_5. They can now write something in the `<input>`. And that value will be used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if($('select').find('option:selected').val() == 'example_5'){

            use input??

            $_COOKIE['input_example'] = $example_1;

        }
        else{
            $_COOKIE['example_1'] = $example_1;
        }
    });
</script>


<?php
    $_COOKIE['example_1'] = $example_1;
?>

<form method="get" action="page2.php">
    <select name="example1">
        <option value="example_1">example_1</option>
        <option value="example_2">example_2</option>
        <option value="example_3">example_3</option>
        <option value="example_4">example_4</option>
        <option value="example_5">example_5</option>
    </select>
    <input name="input_example" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the variable.  Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: PHP and javascript aren't interchangeable, you can't embed PHP code in your javascript code and expect it to run when the javascript runs

Comment: PHP is a server side language

Comment: @PassKit if someone selects `option example_5`, I want it to get the value from input. For example: someone selects `example_5`. They can now write something in the `<input>`. And that value will be used.

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clearer - get it and do what with it? Depending on whether you want to store it in a database, display an alert, store in a cookie for use later or change the browser content will dictate whether to do this in PHP or JS or an AJAX combination of the two.

Comment: @PassKit I want to store it in a database and later show it on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to blo0p3r's answer.

In page2.php, add the following at the very top of the script before any whitespace or HTML is sent:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['example1']) && $_GET['example1'] === "example_5")
  setcookie($_GET['input_example'], 'example_5', time()+3600, '/');
```

Comment: this helped me in the right direction. Thank you. (btw it's setcookie instead of set_cookie.)

Comment: Thks, have changed the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to have a `onChange` listener on the `select` box and then using javascript get the value of the input box using `document.getElementById`.  You can use any *jQuery* shortcut you want, but the methodology would be the same.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpWyW/1/) for a functional example using this technique.

On an unrelated note, be sure to always close your `<input />` tags (probably just a typos :)

### Edit

As per comment : just set the value of the input from a value from the cookies.

```
document.getElementById("input_example").value = getCookie("cookie_name");
```

Where you can write a simple function to get the cookies :

```js
function getCookie(Name) {
  var search = Name + “=”
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) { // if there are any cookies
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
      offset += search.length
      // set index of beginning of value
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(”;”, offset)
      // set index of end of cookie value
      if (end == -1)
        end = document.cookie.length
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
    }
  }
}
```

Tutorial for js cookie function taken [here](http://developers.chrisranjana.com/javascripts/how-to-get-cookie-value-through-javascript-and-displaying-it-in-div-tag.html).

#### See also

[JS Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Using an `onclick` event for a `<select>` (or any other) input seems strange. What if they use their keyboard?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist very good point.  Updated the answer to an onChange listener.  This way as soon as the value is changed the JS fires.  Whether the mouse is used or keyboard.

Comment: thank you for your time, but I'm not sure that I'm looking for this. I want this `$_COOKIE['example'] = $example_1;` to change into `$_COOKIE['input_example'] = $example_1;` when `option example_5` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to check if the from is submitted. Afterward `$_COOKIE['example_1'] = $example_1;` would be something like this:

`$_COOKIE['example_1'] = $_GET['example1'];`